# Unbound method must be called with X instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Tags: python, class, methods

I am playing with [pyelliptic](https://github.com/yann2192/pyelliptic), but I can't use the method `raw_get_ecdh_key` defined in the file *ecc.py*.

Here's my example code:

```
>>> import pyelliptic
>>> pubkey1="0453eb8248f42b00d057bc1adc724c4c841ec75851d6cd86f56f9bae5223219c7d3c7aff832d2383dfec167327ef38e9bf066690a8f94c055b336a607cebc2dddf".decode('hex')
>>> pubkey2="04678b95e902b04817ba258ecd3dbb2150d83850848a3b8523c11d51b6a9f89b93ea82db74ba82ba44fadb050b35eae8b96f3738e88c7c117227303a528c8df985".decode('hex')
>>> pyelliptic.ECC.raw_get_ecdh_key(pubkey1, pubkey2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method raw_get_ecdh_key() must be called with ECC instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

I searched and found many questions on the subject here. I learned that I need to call `ECC()` instead of `ECC`, but it doesn't work any better:

```
>>> pyelliptic.ECC().raw_get_ecdh_key(pubkey1, pubkey2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyelliptic/ecc.py", line 324, in raw_get_ecdh_key
    OpenSSL.EC_KEY_free(own_key)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'own_key' referenced before assignment
```

I can't figure what's wrong. I checked and the variable `own_key` should be referenced.

Comment: Please fix your title - your problem is not with trying to call an instance method from the class.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very obvious bug in pyelliptic - if you look at the code, the part where `own_key` is defined (ecc.py line 301) is wrapped in huge try/finally block. If an exception is raised (and not managed) before line 301 (which is obviously what happened to you), then the execution flow jumps to the `finally` block, which to tries to reference `own_key` which at this point has not yet been defined.

You can fix by cloning the git repo and editing the `raw_get_ecdh_key` function's code so 1. the relevant local variables are defined at the beginning of the function *before* the `try` block (setting them to `None`) and 2. in the finally block these variables are tested against `None` before trying to use them to free resources, ie (untested):

```
def raw_get_ecdh_key(self, pubkey_x, pubkey_y):
    other_key = None
    other_pub_key_x = None
    other_pub_key_y = None
    other_pub_key = None
    own_key = None
    own_priv_key = None

    try:
        # (snip code)
    finally:
        if other_key is not None:
            OpenSSL.EC_KEY_free(other_key)
        if other_pub_key_x is not None:
            OpenSSL.BN_free(other_pub_key_x)
        if other_pub_key_y is not None:
            OpenSSL.BN_free(other_pub_key_y)
        if other_pub_key is not None:
            OpenSSL.EC_POINT_free(other_pub_key)
        if own_key is not None:
            OpenSSL.EC_KEY_free(own_key)
        if own_priv_key is not None:
            OpenSSL.BN_free(own_priv_key)
```

And then run the the unittests (eventually adding some tests for this case) and submit a pull request to the author.

Note that you'll have applied this (untested) fix you *should* have another error - the one that sent you in the `finally` block at first - but at least you should then have more infos about why the call failed.